# Spring Data Repository query hook

Tags: spring, spring-data

In Spring Data is it possible to extend a query that is generated by the find* functions of the repo interfaces?

Given following use case:

My legacy database has an inheritance by table. So given following

```
@Entity public class Person { 
  private int id;
  private String className;
}

@Entity @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id") public class Musician extends Person {
  String instrument;
}

@Entity @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id") public class Lawyer extends Person {
  String discipline;
}
```

My repository for Musician:

```
public interface MusicianRepository extends CrudRepository<Musician, int> {
  List<Musician> findAll();
}
```

Now an entry for a new musician in SQL would be:

```
insert into Person(id, className) values(1, 'Musician');
insert into Musician(id, instrument) values(1, 'piano');
```

When a Musician got migrated to a lawyer the old system added one row to Lawyer table without removing Musician by:

```
insert into Lawyer(id, discipline),  values(1, 'finance');
update Person set ClassName = 'Lawyer' where ID = 1;
```

My MusicianRepo would now find the lawyer since the row in Musician still exists.

I would need some kind of post processor where I could extend the query by adding a where clause with "ClassName = 'Musician'" on all find* methods.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your JPA mapping is just not correct in terms of inheritance.

I think you want to have *"Joined, Multiple Table Inheritance"*

Citing from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined.2C_Multiple_Table_Inheritance):

> Joined inheritance is the most logical inheritance solution because it
>   mirrors the object model in the data model. In joined inheritance a
>   table is defined for each class in the inheritance hierarchy to store
>   only the local attributes of that class. Each table in the hierarchy
>   must also store the object's id (primary key), which is only defined
>   in the root class. All classes in the hierarchy must share the same id
>   attribute. A discriminator column is used to determine which class the
>   particular row belongs to, each class in the hierarchy defines its own
>   unique discriminator value.
>
> Some JPA providers support joined inheritance with or without a
>   discriminator column, some required the discriminator column, and some
>   do not support the discriminator column. So joined inheritance does
>   not seem to be fully standardized yet.

The className column in Person would be your descriminator column. It determines the subclass to instantiate.

Your mapping would be something like this:

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="className")
public class Person { 
      private int id;
      private String className;
    }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Musician")
 public class Musician extends Person {
      String instrument;
    }

    @Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Lawyer")
 public class Lawyer extends Person {
      String discipline;
    }
```

This way if you query for Lawyer entities JPA would automatically add the where clause to just read rows with className=Lawyer

I did not try the mapping - it should just illustrate the way you should be going.

Comment: Hi, it does the joining but does not add the needed condition for className in the where clause of the sql command.